# Prevent losing selected file on postback in Input type File

Tags: javascript, c#, asp-classic

This my Code in which I am taking the input of two files from the user.Input of 2nd file depends upon the extension on First File selected I am deciding whether to take 2nd file input or not.All decisions of taking 2nd file input are fine but After post back First file input get loses its selected file ..Please help me how can I prevent losing First File selection after form submit.
Here is my aspx page code

```
   <tr bgcolor="white" id="tr_SourceFile"  runat="server">
                        <td style="height: 20px">
                            Source File
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="body_text" type="file"  ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="this.form.submit()" id="src_File" name="src_File" runat="server"
                                style="width: 420px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                <%if (ShowCompileAttach) 
                  {%>
                     <tr bgcolor="white" id="tr_CompileFile" runat="server"> 
                        <td style="height: 20px">
                            Compiled File
                        </td>
                        <td style="height: 16px; width: 625px;">
                            <input class="body_text" type="file" id="comp_File" runat="server" style="width: 420px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                  <%} %>
```

This is my .CS code

```
if (IsPostBack && src_File.PostedFile != null)
        {
            if (src_File.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
            {
                OnFileUpload();
            }
        }
  static NameValueCollection sourceFilesExt;
    public void OnFileUpload() 
    {
        string srcFile = src_File.Value;
        if (isReportSourceFile(srcFile, vr_flag))
        {
            ShowCompileAttach = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            ShowCompileAttach = true;
        }
    }
    public static bool isReportSourceFile(string fileName, int vr_flag)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IO.getFileExtension(fileName.ToLower()) == ".rdf")
                {

                    return true;
                }

            return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

            I can't use asp:Fileuploader as I am working on .net 2.0
```

Comment: Does this.form.submit() contain an a AJAX function of some type?

Comment: Do you have a form element that encloses your input elements?

Comment: No it doesn't contain any AJAX function but it is enclosed in Form tag